# Allow anonymous to ASP.NET Web API controller while rest of the application runs under windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET web application that has Windows authentication enabled. I need to write an ASP.NET Web API controller in that application that uses some of the data access logic of the application. I don't want to create a new project for the Web API alone as I need to expose just a small end point that handles a couple of requests.

The Web API clients would consume the service anonymously. To allow this, I tried using AllowAnonymous action filter on both controller as well as the actions. But, when I try hitting the API using Fiddler, the request fails with status 401 saying "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials".

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 14):

I'm a bit late to the party, but ensure that Anonymous Authentication is enabled. Then add:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <location path="api/...">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

To your web.config.

I am assuming you have:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Very important part - Check Anonymous Authentication is enabled, Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Well - all controllers that need authentication need the Authorize attribute (that could be a global filter) - then use AllowAnonymous on the ones that don't need authN.

Then make sure anonymous authentication is enabled in IIS for the vdir - and also make sure there is no global authorize element in web.config.

Comment: Do you mean adding a location element with path pointing to the virtual path? I tried that, but no luck.

Comment: No. Everything is happening at the controller level. Just make sure web.config has *no* authorization element and that anonymous authentication is enabled or allowed (at the IIS level).

Comment: Do I need to allow both windows and anonymous authentications at IIS level? If I do that, it doesn't assign AUTH_USER and LOGON_USER server variables, this is failing the windows authentication.

Comment: Yes you need to allow both.

Comment: But as I mentioned, windows authentication doesn't work properly then. I don't get AD username of the user using server variables. Anyway to make it work?

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but i am having the reverse issue, i need to authorise the connection to the controller to find out who the user is so that only certain data is returned. However, the `this.User.Identity` is empty... Any suggestions please

Comment: Did you get an answer to this @Chris Hammond?

Comment: Hi @ozzy432836 - Sorry for delay, I sort of sorted it, not elegantly but it worked. What I did was that I created a new web app on IIS with Anonymous authentication. Means you have two URLs but as its an API I didn't see an issue with it.

Comment: Yes that was pretty much my solution. The difference is I already had another app on IIS with Anonymous Auth. So I moved the code from the API that required Windows Auth to the one that was already using Anonymous Auth and it solved the problem of this.User.Identity being empty. For now that will do! Thanks! @ChrisHammond

Answer (score 3):

The way I solved the problem, using Visual Studio 2015 and .NET 4.5.2, was to set the Web API project properties to have both **Anonymous Authentication** and **Windows Authentication** set to *Enabled* (note these will also have to be set in the IIS instance).  Then within my controllers I decorated the methods that would require authentication with the `[Authorize]` attribute as well as the name of my custom authentication attribute.

This permitted the default configuration for the controller methods to accept anonymous calls and only the few special methods that required authentication had the extra decorators.  I didn't have to add anything to the **web.config** or **WebApiConfig.cs** files.  The **Global.asax** did have a call to my custom authentication static function which set global values.

Answer (score 0):

If after changing the settings are not working, try `iisreset /start` .

It worked for me:
health webapi controller enabled to anonymous while all other webapi controllers and mvc controllers remained with ntlm windows authentication enabled.
web config doesn't contain  tag at all because the settings was done in IIS level. Windows authentication was enabled and Anonymous was disabled. (site level, authentication settings).
webconfig:

```
<location path="api/health">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```