# Different Authentication Modes for Asp.Net MVC and Web API on the same site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.Net MVC4 intranet site that also has a Web API controller.

I have set Authentication = "Windows" in the web.config.

Is it possible to set the Web API only to allow Anonymous?

** Changes I've made to the WebApiConfig file per suggestions below.

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );      
    // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
    }
}
```

Comment: AllowAnonymous attribute on the Web API controller? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835373/allow-anonymous-to-asp-net-web-api-controller-while-rest-of-the-application-runs

Answer (score 0):

Sure, inside your WebApiConfig class you need to suppress the default host authentication for the web api only, you can do it as the code below:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a Web API 2.2 only feature?

Comment: Yup, it is Web API 2 feature not 1. I believe you are using Web API 1, didn't notice that your project is MVC4. :(

Comment: I've upgraded the project so that I can use API 2.

Comment: Perfect, hope this will solve your issue then, check it and if it worked do not forget it to mark it is as answer :)

Comment: Now it keeps prompting me to go to the login page when I go to the non-api home page via http://Mysite/ If I use http://Mysite/home/index/ it works ok.

Comment: The "fix" didn't affect the outcome. A "401 unauthorized" is still returned.

Comment: I recommend you to check the VS 2013 Web API template (Web API and MVC core dependency) but with individual accounts checked as this image (http://i.imgur.com/1Ucts6z.png), I believe you are missing adding those both lines in class WebApiConfig.cs:

    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

You need to suppress the default authentication (Forms Auth) then add the bearer authentication only for Web API.

Comment: Unfortunately I am limited to VS2012 and it's templates.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I have achived it with the code below. The project uses Forms Authentication for MVC and Basic Authentication for WebAPI. I use Thinktecture library to achive it.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var authConfig = new AuthenticationConfiguration();
        authConfig.AddBasicAuthentication((userName, password) => AuthenticationService.ValidateUser(userName, password));
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthenticationHandler(authConfig));

    }
}
```