# Allows anonymous application on ApiControllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, windows-authentication

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with a Web Api service in C# and .NET Framework 4.5.1.

I have enabled `<authentication mode="Windows" />` on `Web.config`and added the following on ASP.NET MVC Controllers:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"MyDomain\MyRole")]
public class ReportController : Controller
```

But I don't need Windows Authentication on `ApiController`. How can I enable anonymous access to `ApiController`s?

Comment: You should be able to use the api controllers anonymously unless you have specified a `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller method / class.

Comment: I'm asking that because I have had problems with this configuration on an IIS 7. After I have disabled `<authentication mode="Windows" />` to `<authentication mode="None" />`, I have worked with `ApiControllers` without problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow anonymous to ASP.NET Web API controller while rest of the application runs under windows authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835373/allow-anonymous-to-asp-net-web-api-controller-while-rest-of-the-application-runs)

Comment: If you're exposing your api in a particular URL, you can use the solution on the question of the previos comment: allow anonymous acces to a particular location in web.config. If that doesn't work for you, please, let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this for webapi you can use the below in your Web.Config

```
<location path="api">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
 </location>
```

This is saying that for the api controllers, allow any users (denoted by the ?). It might be worth changing that to be more specific if you wanted to do specific controllers.

It also assumes you deny access to all anonymous users and that your web.config authentication is like this

```
<system.web>   <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>  </system.web>
```

However if you want to allow it on the MVC Controllers you can utilise the
**[AllowAnonymous]** attribute.

**Related:**
[Use Anonymous authentication in MVC4 on single controller when the whole application uses Windows Authenticaion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087755/use-anonymous-authentication-in-mvc4-on-single-controller-when-the-whole-applica)

[Disable Windows Authentication for WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588397/disable-windows-authentication-for-webapi)

[Windows Authentication for ASP.NET MVC 4 - how it works, how to test it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224174/windows-authentication-for-net-mvc-4-how-it-works-how-to-test-it)

**Additional Reading:**

[Windows Authentication ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication)

[Authorize Attribute MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx)

[Anonymous Attribute MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: The question asks how to configure anonymous access to Web API, not MVC.

Comment: It says with MVC, and the controller in question is an MVC Controller. I will update Answer regardless - you made me realise the config was missing. So i just updated it to have a ? instead of * and path of api

Comment: Perhaps it's not very clear, but let me quote the title: "allows anonymous app on ApiControllers" and some text from the body of the question: "How can I enable anonymous access to ApiControllers?"

Comment: You are correct, and if you want to reread my previous comment  '...I will update Answer...' 

I have left the original information there as it may prove useful.

Comment: Don't take it amiss ;) I didn't mean to be rude, only to justify my comment.

Comment: It's ok - I read the first part and then brain ignored the last bit haha!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In other words: I don't need Windows Authentication to access `ApiController`s but I need it on MVC's `Controller`s.

Comment: Correct, unless you are manually using the [Authorize] attribute. If you find your self facing 401's use the .config I posted

Comment: I have tested it your `web.config` modification and it works. It works also without `[AllowAnonymous]` on `ApiController`s.